# reset FormControl input

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i'm using angular 5 and i need to know how can i reset somme input, not all input on submit

```js
sForm = new FormGroup({
    Form: new FormGroup({
      pro: new FormControl('')
    }),
    contactForm: new FormGroup({
      client: new FormControl(this.client),
      lastName: new FormControl(''),
      name: new FormControl(''),
      email: new FormControl(''),
      mobile: new FormControl(''),
      cmd: new FormControl('')

    })
  });
```

Comment: Just use the [`FormControl.reset()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset) method, e.g. `souscrireForm.controls.clientName.reset()`

Comment: it's reset all form, i don't wanna reset clientName

Comment: I said you should reset a `control` and not the `form`.

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code will reset only clientName. Please try

```js
    resetSome() {
        this.souscrireForm.reset({
            Form: {...this.souscrireForm.get('Form').value},
            contactForm: { 
                ...this.souscrireForm.get('contactForm').value,
                clientName: null
            }
        });  
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much